# Java varargs to require indefinite number of variables

Tags: java, variadic-functions

I am trying to apply varargs. I have declared a method which requires an indefinite amount of variables like this:

```
private Subject carMonitor;

public AdvancedMonitor(Subject ... carMonitors){
    for (Subject carMonitor : carMonitors){
    this.carMonitor = carMonitor;
    carMonitor.registerObserver(this);
    }
}
```

However, when I try to call it in my main method, I am not able to use anything other than one argument:

```
    BigCar bigCar = new BigCar();
    SmallCar smallCar = new SmallCar();
    AdvancedMonitor doubleAdvancedDisplay1 = new AdvancedMonitor();
    AdvancedMonitor doubleAdvancedDisplay2 = new AdvancedMonitor(bigCar);
    AdvancedMonitor doubleAdvancedDisplay3 = new AdvancedMonitor(bigCar, smallCar);
```

Only the second one works. Why is this?

[image]

Is it related to my interface?

```
public interface Subject {
    public void registerObserver(Observer o);
    public void removeObserver(Observer o);
    public void notifyObservers();
}
```

big car interface -- small car is pretty much the same for now :

```
public class BigCar implements Subject {
    private ArrayList observers;
    private int state;

    public BigCar(){
        observers = new ArrayList();
    }

    public void registerObserver(Observer o){
        observers.add(o);
    }

    public void removeObserver(Observer o){
        int i = observers.indexOf(o);
        if (i >= 0){
            observers.remove(i);
        }
    }

    public void notifyObservers(){
        for (int i = 0; i < observers.size(); i++){
            Observer observer = (Observer)observers.get(i);
            observer.update(state);
        }
    }

    public void stateChanged() {
        notifyObservers();
    }

    public void setState(int state){
        this.state = state;
        stateChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: When you say "Only the second one works", what exactly do you mean? Do you get Compile exception for the other 2? Runtime exception?

Comment: "this.carMonitor = carMonitor", suspicious state change here

Comment: @radoh I get a warning from NetBeans: 'required: Subject found: no arguments reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length'

Comment: @user25976 so does `BigCar` and `SmallCar` implement `Subject` interface?

Comment: @radoh yes, they do. see updated post with the code for my interface

Comment: Well, it **should** work, have a look here - http://ideone.com/pbeZJ0

Comment: Ctrl+click on the constructor name. It will take you to the constructor, and you may find that it was declared to take just one `Subject` argument - perhaps it's another class with the same name, while you were editing one in another directory that's not part of the project.

Answer (score 1):

I write following code:

```
public class Test {
    public static class AdvancedMonitor {
        private String carMonitor;

        public AdvancedMonitor(String... carMonitors) {
            for (String carMonitor : carMonitors) {
                this.carMonitor = carMonitor;
                System.out.println(this.carMonitor);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String bigCar = "bigCar";
        String smallCar = "smallCar";
        System.out.println("step 1");
        AdvancedMonitor doubleAdvancedDisplay1 = new AdvancedMonitor();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("step 2");
        AdvancedMonitor doubleAdvancedDisplay2 = new AdvancedMonitor(bigCar);
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("step 3");
        AdvancedMonitor doubleAdvancedDisplay3 = new AdvancedMonitor(bigCar, smallCar);
    }
}
```

And I have following result:

```
step 1

step 2
bigCar

step 3
bigCar
smallCar
```

In my opinion, all correct. What is wrong in your case? Do you use `logging` or `System.out.println` to debug your problem? It's look like your problem isn't with Java varagrs, but you have some exception in `carMonitor.registerObserver(this)`.

**P.S.** Also, you understand that every AdvancedMonitor has only a one varible carMonitor? And using `new AdvancedMonitor(bigCar, smallCar);` in result you have AdvancedMonitor only with smallCar in `private String carMonitor;`?

**P.P.S.** Also bad idea to use `this` in construstor, because object isn't really create when running construstor.

Comment: It's perfectly fine to use `this` in a constructor to differentiate a field name from an argument name.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the Constructor works.

Please check these statements:
**SmallCar and BigCar both implements Subject**
**class AdvancedMonitor implements Observer**
**AdvancedMonitor doubleAdvancedDisplay is not declared several times** but in your code it is. It should be smth like:

```
AdvancedMonitor doubleAdvancedDisplay1 = new AdvancedMonitor();
AdvancedMonitor doubleAdvancedDisplay2 = new AdvancedMonitor(bigCar);
AdvancedMonitor doubleAdvancedDisplay3 = new AdvancedMonitor(bigCar, smallCar);
```

I hope it'll help you